Finding Transition Point of Two Tangent Parabolas
I have an engineering problem that involves a long cable that is draped (Draped Cable) in a series of reversing parabolas. The high and low points are known, but I need to locate the inflection points; the x-coordinates of the inflection points are known, but not the y-coordinates. The problem is that the focal points of each parabola are not known.

It has been over 30 years since I had to solve a problem like this, and my memory is stuck. I suspect it involves equating the slope of the tangent line of two tangent parabolas and solving from there. Thank you in advance for your help.
I have also attached a real-world example of this problem so I know that it is somehow being solved (note that the values differ from the example above).

Parabolas do not have inflection points, so you are really looking for the transition points where the cable goes from one parabola to the other. Please state what is known about these transitions.

Can you provide a picture? Inflection point is where the acceleration/concavity changes sign. As Lieven mentions, such points don't exist for parabolas since the second derivative/acceleration is constant.

Low Point (vertex) of Parabola #1: LP(0, 3.75); High Point (vertex) of Parabola #2: HP(180, 20.25); Transition Point: TP(144, y); P1 opens up, P2 opens down. Trying to find y.

You need the apertures (coefficients of $x^2$ or equivalent info) for both parabolas as well.

Coefficients and foci are not known.

Be very careful: you mention the cable being folded into a series of parabolas, but are you really sure that it isn't a sinus? Or a series of cosinus hyperbolicus?

Let $a$ and $b$ be the coefficients of the parabola on the left and on the right, respectively. Then you have two coupled equations for $a$ and $b$:
$$
\begin{align}
& 144a=36b\quad\text{(same slope at inflection point)}\\
& 144^2a+36^2b=16.5\quad\text{(total difference of height)}
\end{align}
$$
You can then solve this system and plug the result into
$$
Y=3.75+144^2a
$$
